# What can I do to no longer get jcall error when using read_osm() to display basemap in plot mode for tmap in R?

Tags: java, r

When attempting to display a basemap for a static map or a map in plot mode when using the *tmap* package in R I get a jcall error. Below is the code I ran and the error messages.

Wondering if anyone has an idea on what maybe the issue? I've updated *rJava* package, but perhaps I need an older version. Or am I missing a Java library?

```
c_osm <- read_osm(w1, ext = 1.05)
```

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
>   cl,  :    java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using
>   ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

```
c_osm <- tmaptools::read_osm(w1, ext = 1.05)
```

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
>   cl,  :    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE

Answer (score 4):

To fix it run:

`Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)`

before

`library(OpenStreetMap)`

To fix the display variable.